# How to access Django's field.choices?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way (without using a form) to access a model fields choices value?

I want to do something like `field.choices` and get the list of values either in a view or template.

Answer (score 88):

Sure. Just access the `choices` attribute of a Model field:

```
MyModel._meta.get_field('foo').choices
my_instance._meta.get_field('foo').choices
```

Comment: What if i wanted them in my django templates?

Comment: Anything accessible in your view is accessible in the template, you just need to pass it into the template context. Since this one starts with an underscore, you'll have to manually pass the field instance to the context.

Comment: If you are using named groups in your choices, you might also find the `flatchoices` attribute useful.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita how can I convert it to json?is there any simple method?

Answer (score 14):

If you're declaring your choices like this:

```
class Topic(models.Model):

    PRIMARY = 1
    PRIMARY_SECONDARY = 2
    TOPIC_LEVEL = ((PRIMARY, 'Primary'),
                  (PRIMARY_SECONDARY, 'Primary & Secondary'),)

    topic_level = models.IntegerField('Topic Level', choices=TOPIC_LEVEL,
            default=1)
```

Which is a good way of doing it really. See: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/

Then you can get back the choices simply with `Topic.TOPIC_LEVEL`

Comment: I'm using this way in my view, but instead of getting `Primary, Primary & Secondary` (as it should be, in the example above) i get  `(PRIMARY, 'Primary'), (PRIMARY_SECONDARY, 'Primary & Secondary')`. Why is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: @LjubisaLivac The reason is that you have declared the variable `TOPIC_LEVEL` as tuple of pairs `(database_value, 'readable_value')` and you are now retrieving it exactly as you have input. There are many advantages in doing it, one of them being readability to the next person handling your code. This isn't broken: many applications would rather have the actual database value instead of the one meant to be read by humans. If you just want the strings, you can retrieve them with `[ i[1] for i in Topic.TOPIC_LEVEL ]`.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for `get_fieldname_display()` function.

Comment: Just to clarify, as I had to search for an example, in a template you would do:
`{{ model.get_FIELDNAME_display }}`
where `FIELDNAME` is the name of the field.

So, for the above code, it would be:
`{{ topic.get_topic_level_display }}`