# Grouping in Django View

Tags: python, django

I am trying to group a table output by one of it's columns.  Below is the model (yes, this is a star trek-themed site I'm building...learning django on the way):

```
class ShipClass (models.Model):
    ALLEGIENCE_CHOICES = (
    ('FED', 'Federation'),
    ('KGE', 'Klingon Empire'),
    ('RSE', 'Romulan Star Empire')
    )
    Origin = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ALLEGIENCE_CHOICES, default='FED')
    ClassName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    NumberOfCrew = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ClassName

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("Origin", "ClassName")
```

What I'm trying to do is output the view of this model in such a way that the list appears to be grouped by it's Allegiance choice.  How do I perform grouping in the template-level?

such as

- Federation

  - Danube
  - Galaxy
- Klingon

  - Bird of Prey

Thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between the items in the tables and sub-tables? I guess Federation is the Origin field but how about the Danube and Galaxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged)

```
 qs = ShipClass.objects.order_by("Origin", "Classname")


 {% for entry in qs %}
    {% ifchanged entry.Origin %}
       {{ entry.Origin }}
    {% endifchanged %}
    {{ entry.Classname }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Sax.  I like your idea, but I'm getting the error:  
argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable   help??

Comment: strange. just checked with different class. where did u put this line `qs = ShipClass.objects.order_by("Origin", "Classname")` ? django version ?

Comment: I got it.  First render_to_response requires the tag { "qs" : qs } as the recordset (my silliness in being a noob)....second, ClassName, not Classname.  Otherwise, Perfection.  Thanks.

Comment: Origin is a three-letter code.  Any chance the objects class can give me the full name?

Comment: use `{{ entry.get_Origin_display }}` instead of `{{ entry.Origin }}`. Might I also suggest to follow [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (ie attribute lowercase, classes CapWords...) ? It

Answer (score 0):

in your view you can build a dictionary whose keys are the allegiance names and values are the list of classNames for that allegiance. To get the keys you can first [access your model's choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165924/access-djangos-field-choices) and then loop through each to make a filter query to get the corresponding className lists, something like:

```
starship_classes_by_allegiance = {}
for choice in ShipClass._meta.get_field('Origin').choices:  
    allegiance_id, allegiance_label = choice
    starship_classes_by_allegiance[allegiance_label] = ShipClass.objects.filter(Origin=allegiance_id).values('ClassName').distinct()
```

then you can iterate over this dict in your template like:

```
{% for allegiance_label in starship_classes_by_allegiance %}

    {{ allegiance_label }}

    <ul>
    {% for class_name in starship_classes_by_allegiance.allegiance_label %}

        <li>{{ class_name }}</li>

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```