# Returning the human-readable element of a Choice Field in DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do I return the human readable element of a Choice field in a Serializer Class. Sample code below.

```
from rest_framework import serializers  
from model_utils import Choices
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

COMPANY_TYPE = Choices(
    (1, 'Public', _('Public Company')),
    (2, 'Private', _('Private Company')),
    (3, 'Other', _('Other Type')),
)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=COMPANY_TYPE)
    company_type_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source=COMPANY_TYPE[1])   # <=== This is the issue

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'company_type', 'company_type_name')
```

If say an entry in the company table has `company_type = 1`, and a user makes an API request, I want to include the extra field of `company_type_name` with the value `Public Company`.

So the issue is am unable to pass the current value of `company_type` to the serializer so that it can return the String value of the Choice Field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12165924/7636315  is this related to ur issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with method field and by [get_Foo_dispay()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

```
company_type_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_company_type_name(self, obj):
    return obj.get_company_type_display()
```

Comment: Thanks for the the Django Link. Helps to understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

From the [DRF Oficial DC](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#choice-selection-fields) the `choices` must be a **list of valid values**, or a **list of (key, display_name) tuples**
So your choices must be in following format,

```
COMPANY_TYPE = (
    (1, 'Public'),
    (2, 'Private'),
    (3, 'Other'),
)
```

NB : `model_utils.Choices` does the same thing
I think you need a `SerializerMethodField` with `read_only=True` rather than a `ReadOnlyField`. So Change your serializer as below,

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_company_type_name(self, obj):
        return COMPANY_TYPE.__dict__.get('_display_map').get(obj['company_type'])

    company_type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=COMPANY_TYPE)
    company_type_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True, source='get_company_type_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'company_type', 'company_type_name')
```

Comment: When I upgraded to `django==2.0.6`, the answer by @sachin doesn't work but this one by @jerin works albeit with a slight change. Instead of `.get(obj['company_type']`, what is working is `.get(obj.company_type)`. Am not sure why..

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to return human readable value and also want the choices to appear in the Swagger integration.. Example: DRF-YASG integration. You need to do something like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    my_field = serializers.ChoiceField(
        source='get_my_field_display',
        choices=MyFieldChoices.labels
    )
    ...
```

and you should have something like: `class MyFieldChoices(models.TextChoices)` defined somewhere and used in the model definition.

By doing that,you'll be able to return the human readable text and Swagger UI will have the it as enum choices.